# Getting "cutom_image_url" for a Page->tabs

Tags: api, facebook-graph-api

While editing in Facebook application, we get "Custom_name" in "page->tabs->custom_name" property..

Similarly, while editing we want to show user his custom tab image. Is there any way to retrieve "custom_image_url" for user in Edit Mode in our application?

As this property is there in "Update" method, but not in "Read" method.

Can anyone help, how can we read Tab 's "custom_image_url" from Graph API?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can access the image of an Application running as Page Tab from `tabs` connection of a page (the image is returned in `image_url` property):

```
http://graph.facebook.com/PAGE_ID/tabs/APP_ID
```